# jXLS: Generar Excel usando plantillas Excel

Tags: java, excel, template, jxl

Buenos días: estoy haciendo uso de la librería jXLS de java para poder usar un excel como plantilla y cargar los valores de manera dinámica. Este sería el excel de prueba que estoy usando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de un excel sencillo con una variblae ${names} que será cargada desde código. El problema es que al ejecutar el código la variable no recoge el valor que le paso. Este sería el trozo de código del micro en ejecución:

```
@Override
public void generateExcelMeeting(String meetingId)
        throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, UrbanitaeBusinessException, InstanceNotFoundException {

    ShareHolderMeeting meeting = this.shareHolderMeetingService.getShareHolderMeeting(meetingId);

    //List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");
    //File file = new File("~\\src\\main\\resources\\juntas.xlsx");
    File file = new File("temporal.xlsx");

    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("salidaJuntas.xlsx")) {
            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("names", "ejemplo");
            JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

¿Por qué no carga la varible ${names}?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución, simplemente es que las variables dentro del excel no deben introducirse en texto plano en la celda, sino que hay que introducir un comentario en la celda y ahí indicar la "fórmula."